# FieldPluginBase: How to test based on views field raw value?

Tags: views, 8

I know that the render method is not the right place to do conditional logic but I have no clue where I should implement my tests.

This is my render method I want to access the raw value of a field to do a test on it (conditional field):

```
  public function render(ResultRow $values) {

    $field_abnormal_category = $this->view->field['field_abnormal_category']->original_value->__toString();

    if($field_abnormal_category == 'No') {
      $field_category_image = $this->view->field['field_category_image']->original_value->__toString();
    }
    else {
      $field_category_image = '';
    }

    return [
    '#type' => 'inline_template',
    '#template' => $field_category_image
    ];

  }
```

The `original_value` object is returning the translation not the original string.

How can I access the original value of my field (not translated)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the untranslated field value get first the untranslated entity:

```
if ($entity = $this->getEntity($values)) {
  $untranslated_entity = $entity->getUntranslated();
  $untranslated_value = $untranslated_entity->field_example->value;
}
```